# It seems no directly mapping when set a grub boot parameter compare to set a sysctl parameter?

Tags: grub, sysctl

There is no direct mapping when setting a grub boot parameter compared to a sysctl parameter.

My question is that there are two locations ( grub and sysctl config ) that may be set to the same feature/config, but the variable name are different.

For example, we can't see `panic_on_oops` in grub parameter.

ref:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.0/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html

Another example,

We can adjust the `kernel.panic` of sysctl from the grub command, for example, by setting `panic=10` in the grub command.